# How to emit an event based on its event selector?

Tags: solidity, events

Starting with solidity v0.8.15 we can now get an event selector just as we used for functions.

```
event.selector
```

Is it possible at this point to emit an event dynamically based on its selector? Something like:

```
event E1(bytes32 arg1, bytes32 arg2);
event E2(bytes32 arg1, bytes32 arg2);

function foo() public {
    dynamicEmit(E1.selector, 0x00, 0x00);
    dynamicEmit(E2.selector, 0x00, 0x00);
}

function dynamicEmit(bytes32 eventSelector, bytes32 arg1, bytes32 arg2) internal {
    // emit here event based on selector
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You'd only have to do a simple `if`:

```js
    event E1(bytes32 arg1, bytes32 arg2);
    event E2(bytes32 arg1, bytes32 arg2);

    function foo() public {
        dynamicEmit(E1.selector, 0x00, 0x00);
        dynamicEmit(E2.selector, 0x00, 0x00);
    }

    function dynamicEmit(bytes32 eventSelector, bytes32 arg1, bytes32 arg2) internal {
        // emit here event based on selector

        if(E1.selector == eventSelector) {
            emit E1(arg1, arg2);
        } else if(E2.selector == eventSelector) {
            emit E2(arg1, arg2);
        }

    }
```

In Remix, it prints something like:

[image]

It's not possible to "call" or "emit" an event directly from outside of the contract. An event is not a function. Even though it has a selector, it's not compiled nor used to access it directly. We cannot even declare an event as `public`.

I compiled the code above and this is the running bytecode:

`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`

I then decompiled here: https://ethervm.io/decompile

And the entry point function of the decompiled contract, `main`, looks like this:

```js
function main() {
        memory[0x40:0x60] = 0x80;
        var var0 = msg.value;
    
        if (var0) { revert(memory[0x00:0x00]); }
    
        if (msg.data.length < 0x04) { revert(memory[0x00:0x00]); }
    
        var0 = msg.data[0x00:0x20] >> 0xe0;
    
        if (var0 != 0xc2985578) { revert(memory[0x00:0x00]); }
    
        var var1 = 0x0038;
        func_003A();
        stop();
    }
```

The code only has one public function, `foo()`. And if we calculate the `keccak256` hash of it, then we can see that is:

`c2985578b8f3b75f7dc66a767be2a4ef7d7c2224896a1c86e92ccf30bae678b7`

You can calculated it yourself here: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

If you take the first 4 bytes of that hash, you endup with `c2985578`. If you search those bytes in the `main()` function, you will find it at line:

```js
//...
if (var0 != 0xc2985578) { revert(memory[0x00:0x00]); }
//...
```

As you can see, since there's only 1 public function, there's only 1 check here. And if you 'call' a 'function' that does not have that selector, then it reverts. Thus, we cannot 'call' an event directly.

Event `E1(bytes32,bytes32)` `keccak256` hash is: 9a6311b27884bd845f20acbd9a955a4d2b083bc8631271b7520f317d3b4019c7

Event `E2(bytes32,bytes32)` `keccak256` hash is:
1000096eb75ded08a4c6ed11be5789e871886380989efb20fff024b38dadc216

We can find those hashes in the decompiled code, but not in the `main()` function which is the entry point of the contract.

```js
    function func_003A() {
        var var0 = 0x006b;
        var var1 = 0x9a6311b27884bd845f20acbd9a955a4d2b083bc8631271b7520f317d3b4019c7;
        var var2 = 0x00 << 0x00;
        var var3 = 0x00 << 0x00;
        func_009E(var1, var2, var3);
    
    label_006B:
        var0 = 0x009c;
        var1 = 0x1000096eb75ded08a4c6ed11be5789e871886380989efb20fff024b38dadc216;
        var2 = 0x00 << 0x00;
        var3 = 0x00 << 0x00;
        func_009E(var1, var2, var3);
    
    label_009C:
    }
    
    function func_009E(var arg0, var arg1, var arg2) {
        if (!(0x9a6311b27884bd845f20acbd9a955a4d2b083bc8631271b7520f317d3b4019c7 - arg0)) {
            var0 = 0x9a6311b27884bd845f20acbd9a955a4d2b083bc8631271b7520f317d3b4019c7;
            var1 = 0x00f6;
            var2 = arg1;
            var4 = memory[0x40:0x60];
            var3 = arg2;
            var1 = func_0183(var2, var3, var4);
            var temp1 = memory[0x40:0x60];
            log(memory[temp1:temp1 + var1 - temp1], [stack[-2]]);
            return;
        } else if (0x1000096eb75ded08a4c6ed11be5789e871886380989efb20fff024b38dadc216 - arg0) {
        label_0164:
            return;
        } else {
            var var0 = 0x1000096eb75ded08a4c6ed11be5789e871886380989efb20fff024b38dadc216;
            var var1 = 0x015b;
            var var2 = arg1;
            var var3 = arg2;
            var var4 = memory[0x40:0x60];
            var1 = func_0183(var2, var3, var4);
            var temp0 = memory[0x40:0x60];
            log(memory[temp0:temp0 + var1 - temp0], [stack[-2]]);
            goto label_0164;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sure, although I was searching for a solution like when you use call with function selectors, when you encode it with parameters

Comment: I updated the answer. Take a look.

Comment: Clear, hope in the future versions we will be able to emit events "dynamically"

Comment: To be more specific: emitting events "dynamically" internally, not from outside the contract (which of course defeats challenges the paradigm quite a bit). There are use cases where it could be useful